# C# DirectX SolidColorBrush draws always Black

Tags: c#, drawing, directx, solidcolorbrush

I am creating a SolidColorBrush and draw with it like that:

```
public int CreateBrush(Color color) {
    if (color.A == 0) {
        color = Color.FromArgb(255, color);
    }

    _brushContainer.Add(new SolidColorBrush(_device, new RawColor4(color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A / 255.0f)));
    return _brushContainer.Count - 1;
}

int _redBrush = overlay.Graphics.CreateBrush(Color.FromArgb(1, 198 / 255, 17 / 255, 17 / 255));

overlay.Graphics.FillCircle(10 + playerRadarPos.x, overlay.Height - height - 10, 5, colors[p.PlayerInfo.Value.ColorId]);
```

Now when I draw using this brush the color is always black. When I create if with the values r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 for example it works. Has anyone an idea how I can fix that or why it is only drawing black.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Color.FromArgb (if this is the class from System.Drawing) expect 0-255 byte values, so you're basically passing an almost black color when do do this: `Color.FromArgb(1, 198 / 255, 17 / 255, 17 / 255)`

Comment: If I understood you right I should do it like Color.From(1, 198, 17, 17). When I do this it is always white. I already had this issue with the SolidColorBrush from DirectX (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266650/directx-c-sharp-solidbrush-is-drawing-white/64266825#64266825).

Comment: Color.FromArgb(1, 198, 17, 17) is ~red almost transparent, so quasi invisible. RawColor4 is using 0..1 values. Just make the whole thing consistent. You can't build RawColor4 from Color.R for example, you must divide all R,G,B by 255f, like you do with A